# Why does % work and / does not in filtering out even numbers?

Tags: python

Compare these two blocks, there's only an operator difference;

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i / 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
```

and

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Why does the second block of code work in successfully filtering out even numbers while the first block does not? I can't wrap the logic around my head. Intuitively any even number should be divisible by 2, so why does the first block not work and prints every number in the range?

Comment: Why would you expect `i / 2` to ever equal 0, except when i == 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Becasuse `%` takes the reminder of the division ([ref](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html), [ref](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/)), and `/` gives you the result of the divison ([ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/division-operator-in-python/)).

`i / 2 == 0` is only `True` if `i=0`.

`i % 2 == 0` is only `True` if `i` is divisible by 2 (ie you can divide it without getting a [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder), ie it is [even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics))).

Answer (score 1):

Because modulo (`%`) checks divisibility, while division (`/`) doesn't. This is more of a math question than programming.

If a number N is divisible by another number M, N mod M will be 0. Meanwhile, N *divided by* M will be K, where K times M equals N, and K will be a whole number since N is divisible by M.

So if you wanted to check divisibility using division, you could check if K is a whole number:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    k = i / 2
    if k == int(k):
        continue
    print(i)
```

But don't do this. Modulo is much simpler.

#### References

- [Tutorial: Numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers)
- [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use division as operation then that's the solution.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if (i // 2) * 2 != i:
        continue
    print(i)
```

The difference is that by using `%` you will be getting the modulo `% 2` gives you 1 or 0 depending if the number is even or odd. `/2` will give you the number divided by 2.

Comment: This doesn't work. Maybe you're thinking of floor division (which was what `/` did on Python 2 if both operands were ints).

Comment: *//* then, I am sorry, thank you for correcting me

Comment: Now you have the logic backwards. OP wants to filter out even numbers, not odd numbers.

Comment: (Sorry @Diana, one of my earlier claims about this method not working was wrong.)